# Accessing a matrix element in the "Mat" object (not the CvMat object) in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, matrix, opencv

How to access elements by row, col in OpenCV 2.0's new "Mat" class? The documentation is linked below, but I have not been able to make any sense of it. 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat

Answer (score 64, accepted):

On the documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat

It says:

> (...) if you know the matrix element
>   type, e.g. it is float, then you can
>   use at<>() method

That is, you can use:

```
Mat M(100, 100, CV_64F);
cout << M.at<double>(0,0);
```

Maybe it is easier to use the `Mat_` class. It is a template wrapper for `Mat`. 
`Mat_` has the `operator()` overloaded in order to access the elements.

Comment: How do you set a particular value to some particular index of M?

Comment: @sumit the at<>() method returns a reference to the element. You can use: 
M.at<double>(0, 0) = value;

Comment: I'm pretty sure the example is this answer is flawed. I believe at does a unsafe cast internally so using at with double on a uint matrix would produce undesired/corrupted results. Suggesting correction.

Comment: @Catskul You are right. The text is fine, but the example should say *CV_64F*. I have corrected it.

Comment: What if I don't know the type of a `Mat`?

Comment: @nn0p You can use the method Mat::type() in order to get the type.

Answer (score 13):

The ideas provided above are good. For fast access (in case you would like to make a real time application) you could try the following:

```
//suppose you read an image from a file that is gray scale
Mat image = imread("Your path", CV_8UC1);
//...do some processing
uint8_t *myData = image.data;
int width = image.cols;
int height = image.rows;
int _stride = image.step;//in case cols != strides
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        uint8_t val = myData[ i * _stride + j];
        //do whatever you want with your value
    }
}
```

Pointer access is much faster than the Mat.at<> accessing. Hope it helps!

Comment: Pointer access cost is exactly same as Mat.at<> (when compiling in release). The only difference is asserts, that are active unless the code is compiled in debug mode.

Comment: Why would pointer access be much faster than the `Mat.at` version?

Answer (score 10):

Based on what @J. Calleja said, you have two choices

### Method 1 - Random access

If you want to random access the element of Mat, just simply use

```
Mat.at<data_Type>(row_num, col_num) = value;
```

### Method 2 - Continuous access

If you want to continuous access, OpenCV provides Mat iterator compatible with `STL iterator` and it's more `C++` style

```
MatIterator_<double> it, end;
for( it = I.begin<double>(), end = I.end<double>(); it != end; ++it)
{
    //do something here
}
```

or

```
for(int row = 0; row < mat.rows; ++row) {
    float* p = mat.ptr(row); //pointer p points to the first place of each row
    for(int col = 0; col < mat.cols; ++col) {
         *p++;  // operation here
    }
}
```

If you have any difficulty to understand how Method 2 works, I borrow the picture from a blog post in the article [Dynamic Two-dimensioned Arrays in C](http://www.annigeri.in/2011/11/dynamic-two-dimensioned-arrays-in-c.html), which is much more intuitive and comprehensible.

See the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OCV goes out of its way to make sure you can't do this without knowing the element type, but if you want an easily codable but not-very-efficient way to read it type-agnostically, you can use something like

```
double val=mean(someMat(Rect(x,y,1,1)))[channel];
```

To do it well, you do have to know the type though. The at<> method is the safe way, but direct access to the data pointer is generally faster if you do it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

## For `cv::Mat_<T> mat` just use `mat(row, col)`

Accessing elements of a matrix with specified type [cv::Mat_< _Tp >](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html) is more comfortable, as you can skip the template specification. This is pointed out in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#details) as well.

**code:**

```
cv::Mat1d mat0 = cv::Mat1d::zeros(3, 4);
std::cout << "mat0:\n" << mat0 << std::endl;
std::cout << "element: " << mat0(2, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

cv::Mat1d mat1 = (cv::Mat1d(3, 4) <<
    1, NAN, 10.5, NAN,
    NAN, -99, .5, NAN,
    -70, NAN, -2, NAN);
std::cout << "mat1:\n" << mat1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "element: " << mat1(0, 2) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(3, 4, CV_32F, 0.0);
std::cout << "mat2:\n" << mat2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "element: " << mat2.at<float>(2, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

**output:**

```
mat0:
[0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
element: 0

mat1:
[1, nan, 10.5, nan;
 nan, -99, 0.5, nan;
 -70, nan, -2, nan]
element: 10.5

mat2:
[0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
element: 0
```