# Print out the values of a (Mat) matrix in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to dump the values of a matrix in OpenCV to the console using cout. I quickly learned that I do not understand OpenvCV's type system nor C++ templates well enough to accomplish this simple task.

Would a reader please post (or point me to) a little function or code snippet that prints a Mat?

Regards,
Aaron

PS: Code that uses the newer C++ Mat interface as opposed to the older CvMat interface is preferential.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

See the first answer to [Accessing a matrix element in the "Mat" object (not the CvMat object) in OpenCV C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844736/accesing-a-matrix-element-in-the-mat-object-not-the-cvmat-object-in-opencv-c)
Then just loop over all the elements in `cout << M.at<double>(0,0);`  rather than just 0,0

Or better still with the C++ interface:

```
cv::Mat M;
cout << "M = " << endl << " "  << M << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Brilliant. I should haves shoved a Mat to cout in the first place just to see if someone had implemented <<. A little more experimentation and trust would have payed off for me.

Comment: I have just asked [a question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011797/opencv-2-1-where-is-ostream-operator-for-cvmat). Is the ostream operator<< available in 2.1 and where is this stuff documented?

Comment: @ahoffer, funny you mentioned that: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga3557054d1f0f079cf5e60a44851e4c70

Comment: One thing to add: Make sure you include `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>` and not `#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>` as the operator is overloaded elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using opencv3, you can print Mat like `python numpy style`:

```
Mat xTrainData = (Mat_<float>(5,2) << 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2);

cout << "xTrainData (python)  = " << endl << format(xTrainData, Formatter::FMT_PYTHON) << endl << endl;
```

Output as below, you can see it'e more readable, see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html)  for more information.

[image]

But in most case, there is no need to output all the data in Mat, you can output by row range like 0 ~ 2 row:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //row: 6, column: 3，unsigned one channel
    Mat image1(6, 3, CV_8UC1, 5);

    // output row: 0 ~ 2
    cout << "image1 row: 0~2 = "<< endl << " "  << image1.rowRange(0, 2) << endl << endl;

    //row: 8, column: 2，unsigned three channel
    Mat image2(8, 2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(1, 2, 3));

    // output row: 0 ~ 2
    cout << "image2 row: 0~2 = "<< endl << " "  << image2.rowRange(0, 2) << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output as below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double data[4] = {-0.0000000077898273846583732, -0.03749374753019832, -0.0374787251930463, -0.000000000077893623846343843};
    Mat src = Mat(1, 4, CV_64F, &data);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        cout << setprecision(3) << src.at<double>(0,i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think using the `matrix.at<type>(x,y)` is not the best way to iterate trough a Mat object!
If I recall correctly `matrix.at<type>(x,y)` will iterate from the beginning of the matrix each time you call it(I might be wrong though).
I would suggest using `cv::MatIterator_`

```
cv::Mat someMat(1, 4, CV_64F, &someData);;
cv::MatIterator_<double> _it = someMat.begin<double>();
for(;_it!=someMat.end<double>(); _it++){
    std::cout << *_it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the above excellent answers, you can print out Mat values by FileStorage, of course if your case considers utilizing a file

```
// create our writer 
FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "Result" << Mat::eye(5,5, CV_64F);
// release the file 
fs.release();

// read file
FileStorage fs2("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);

Mat r2;
fs2["Result"] >> r2;
std::cout << r2 << std::endl;

fs2.release();
```