# OpenCV 2.1: where is ostream operator<< for cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970988/print-out-the-values-of-a-mat-matrix-in-opencv-c), I am attempting to print out the contents of a `cv::Mat` to standard output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.hpp>

int main() {

  cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::ones(10, 10, CV_32S);
  std::cout << m << "\n";

}
```

This results in the error

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << m’
```

I am using gcc 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.10, and installed opencv, excluding the examples, following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV). My question is, is the operator available in 2.1 and if so, how do I get it?

Comment: If the operator is not defined, you might need to upgrade to 2.2 or above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update to OpenCV 2.2 (or higher) and `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

It's defined at `modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp`

Comment: Thanks. After a rather painful installation of opencv 2.3.1 it works. The only header needed for the example is <opencv/cv.h>.

Answer (score 2):

If the operator is not defined, you might need to upgrade to 2.2 or above. 
Documented [Here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp?rev=7199) Its where you can find the overloaded operators code.