# Access to CV_32SC1 nx1 opencv matrix

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have an artificial matrix which I pass to the [EM Gaussian Mixture Model](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html) algorithm in [OpenCV - version 3.0.0](http://opencv.org/) of the form :

```
[1.1, 3.2;
 1.15, 3.1500001;
 3.0999999, 4.1999998;
 3.2, 4.3000002;
 5, 5]
```

I call the GMM prediction  via:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::EM> source_model = cv::ml::EM::create();
source_model->setClustersNumber(3);
cv::Mat logs;
cv::Mat labels;
cv::Mat probs;
source_model->trainEM( openCVPointCloud,logs,labels,probs)
```

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html) states about the matrix **labels** which I am interested in:

> **labels** – The optional output 'class label' for each sample: 
>   labels_i = {arg max}*k(p*{i,k}), i=1..N (indices of the most probable mixture component for each sample). It has nsamples x 1 size and 'CV_32SC1' type.

My non working access to 'labels' prints (0,0,0,0,0) instead of expected (0,0,1,1,2) which is plotted via

```
std::cout << labels <<std::endl;
```

. I need though working with the integer indices to work with my original [PCL point cloud](http://pointclouds.org/) which I want to cluster via poitn cloud features:

```
std::cout << labels.data[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << labels.data[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << labels.data[2] << std::endl;
std::cout << labels.data[3] << std::endl;
std::cout << labels.data[4] << std::endl;
```

The code fragments wrapped together in an untested minimal example (I have problems with qmake without using my frame work):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat openCVPointCloud(5, 2,  CV_32FC(1));
    {
        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values1 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(0,0);
        values1.val[0] = 1.1;

        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values2 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(0,1);
        values2.val[0] = 3.2;
    }

    {
        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values1 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(1,0);
        values1.val[0] = 1.15;

        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values2 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(1,1);
        values2.val[0] = 3.15;
    }

    {
        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values1 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(2,0);
        values1.val[0] = 3.1;

        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values2 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(2,1);
        values2.val[0] = 4.2;
    }

    {
        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values1 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(3,0);
        values1.val[0] = 3.2;

        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values2 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(3,1);
        values2.val[0] = 4.3;
    }

    {
        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values1 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(4,0);
        values1.val[0] = 5;

        cv::Vec<float,1>  & values2 =   openCVPointCloud.at<cv::Vec<float,1> >(4,1);
        values2.val[0] = 5;
    }

    std::cout << openCVPointCloud << std::endl;

    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::EM> source_model = cv::ml::EM::create();
    source_model->setClustersNumber(3);
    cv::Mat logs;
    cv::Mat labels;
    cv::Mat probs;
    if(source_model->trainEM( openCVPointCloud,logs,labels,probs))
    {
        std::cout << "true train em";
        std::cout << labels.data[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << labels.data[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << labels.data[2] << std::endl;
        std::cout << labels.data[3] << std::endl;
        std::cout << labels.data[4] << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout <<"false train em" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

What can I do to get access to the integer numbers stored in **labels**?

This [stackexchange topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844736/accesing-a-matrix-element-in-the-mat-object-not-the-cvmat-object-in-opencv-c) states, that if I know the matrix element type I can use the templated at() function. The api states that the label Matrix is of type $CV_32SC1$. Accessing now via:

```
  std::cout << labels.at<CV_32SC1>(2,0) << std::endl;
```

Results in the following error:

```
  invalid template argument for '_Tp', type expected
```

At the time of creation of this question I was also 100% sure I tested

```
  std::cout << labels.at<int>(2,0) << std::endl;
```

also which plotted 0 (and should have been 1). Code in front of me after accepted answer adaptian though prooves me wrong. Might be a duplicate because of a typo I did not see for some hours and the "typo" might have been [QT's qdebug()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) usage instead of [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout). If still considered valuable someone might improve the constructor in the minimal example I provided and remove this sentence and the following. I still hope for a one line solution which I yet failed to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way to print `Mat` value is to use [`operator<<`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4.9/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp#L3869). You already have it.

Your `cv::Mat labels` has type `CV_32SC1`. It contain 32 bit signed integer elements. So you can access items by `labels.at<int>` method.

Better way to access items is to use iterator [`cv::MatIterator_< _Tp >`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dfe/classcv_1_1MatIterator__.html):

```
for(cv::MatIterator_<int> it(labels.begin<int>()); it != labels.end<int>(); it++)
{
  std::cout << (*it) << std::endl; // int i = *it
}
```